# Usefulness of absolute value in optimization algorithms

Tags: functional-analysis, optimization, absolute-value

In a course of Optimization Algorithms at university, professor said that in every algorithm the objective/object function/function cost is defined as:
$$f(\bar x)=\lvert x_0 - g(\bar x)\rvert^{2}$$
where $x_0$ is the actual (or effective) requirement value the algorithm needs to reach, $\bar x$ is an attempt solution vector, $f$ defined as $f:\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$, $g$ defined the same as $f$, and $g$ could be a simulator/another function calculating the $\bar x$ vector.

My curiosity is about that absolute value.

I asked the professor what is the usefulness of that absolute value, since the power of two should turn that difference to a positive value anyway. He replied that ***it helps to reduce errors***, and it's a matter of functional analysis (calculus IV ?), so I don't have the bases to understand it.

My question is: is that right? Is there the possibility to understand in *simple mathematics* why that absolute value is useful, and why I should not write simply $$f(\bar x)=( x_0 - g(\bar x) )^{2}$$
?

I'm an italian computer engineer studying in Italy and my background are just Calculus I and II.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Of course these are the same and you don't need any kind of background to understand this. Probably, the professor said this out of methodical considerations: namely, if your $x$ is not a scalar but, say, a vector, the analogous function will be $f(x)=||x-x_0||^2$ where $||x||$ is a vector norm, and the expression directly generalizes $|x-x_0|^2$. On the other hand, $(x-x_0)^2$ would be undefined in the vector case.

Comment: I forgot to say that $x$ and $x_0$ are vectors. I'll update my question.

Comment: In that case, how do you define $g(x)=x^2$?

Comment: Do you mean something like: $g: \mathbb R^{n} \to \mathbb R$?

Comment: Exactly, it should operate from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}$. This is nothing like $g(x) = x*x$ that you can use in the scalar case.

Comment: Yes, it's exactly like you said. I'll update my question with the definition of $f(x)$.

Comment: What I mean is that you cannot simply write $x^2$ in the vector case because this does not make sense. Do you get what I mean?

Comment: Ah ok.. Now I got it. The absolute value and the power of two have to be applied to a scalar, so f have to change to $f(\bar x)=\lvert x_0 - g(\bar x)\rvert^{2}$ where g is another function/simulator of the $\bar x$ vector, and is defined as f, $g: \Bbb R{^n} \to \Bbb R$. Is now a little more clear and mathematically correct? :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37011/discussion-between-vossler-and-bebo).